# calling the sum of certain values only from a parameter array

Tags: c#, loops

I am trying to figure out how to call the sum of all values under 10 from a parameter array.

So far I have figured out how to call the value of a values. Any thoughts on how I could/should get this figure?

```
static int SumVals(params int[] vals)//parameter array
    {
        int sum = 0;
        foreach (int val in vals) //for each integer value 
        {
            sum += val; //sum equals sum plus val. returns all values added together
        }
        return sum;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int sum = SumVals(100, 5, 2, 9, 800);
        Console.WriteLine("Summed Values = {0}", sum);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an if statement in your loop to only add values < 10

```
foreach (int val in vals)
{
    if(val < 10)
    {
        sum += val;
    }
}
```

Comment: I should have thought of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
static int SumVals(params int[] vals)
{
    return vals.Where(i => i < 10).Sum();
}
```

Comment: It's @Denys who gave the answer not me, but he is using Linq: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx

Comment: Thanks to both of you. That gets the desired result. I haven't got up to Linq in my learning yet so you've introduced a whole realm of capabilities to me! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

```
static int SumVals(params int[] vals)//parameter array
    {
        int sum = 0;
        foreach (int val in vals) //for each integer value 
        {
            if(val < 10) //only add to the sum if value is less than 10
                 sum += val; //sum equals sum plus val. returns all values added together
        }
        return sum;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int sum = SumVals(100, 5, 2, 9, 800);
        Console.WriteLine("Summed Values = {0}", sum);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    foreach (int val in vals) //for each integer value 
    {
        if(val <10)
         sum += val; //sum equals sum plus val. returns all values added together
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to do that:

```
static int SumVals(params int[] vals)//parameter array
{
    return vals.Where(v => v < 10).Sum();
}
```

You have to put `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file to make it work.

Comment: becoz , do you use sword to cut the apple?

Comment: `Enumerable.Where` method has almost exactly the same code, so what's the point in that kind of duplication?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
static int SumVals(params int[] vals)//parameter array
    {
        int sum = 0;
        foreach (int val in vals) //for each integer value 
        {
            if (val >=10) continue;
            sum += val; //sum equals sum plus val. returns all values added together
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static int SumVals(params int[] vals)//parameter array
{
     return vals.Where(x => x < 10).Sum();
}
```